# file_get_contents on local wamp server not working

Tags: php

I simply cant wrap my head around why this simple code won't work on my local wamp server where i have other sites running.

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('C:\Users\Computer\input.txt', true);

echo $file;

?>
```

The file is where it should be.
I get the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(C:\Users\Computer\input.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Computer\Dropbox\htdocs\ny\www\php\day2\code.php on line 3
```

But the file is exactly where it should be.
The file has all possible permissions to true (read, write ect.) in windows except for "special permissions".

What is not working correctly?

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: `echo $string;`? where's that defined? < oh, and this is a sidenote. check your permissions also.

Comment: I would assume the user that the webserver is running under doesn't have read access to your user directory.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Wouldn't that produce a permission error instead of a "no such file" error?

Comment: @Fred-ii- my bad, but the error is still the same.

Comment: Does the output of `var_export(glob('C:\Users\Computer\*'));` contain input.txt? Or is it false/null?

Comment: @Barmar Not sure. If you can't access the parent directory would it error or say can't find file under that path or say it can't find the file? I don't have a windows box with php to test. Also, I believe the user folders might have some special permissions.

Comment: *Hm...* could it be related to administrator permissions on the folder/file maybe that are required?

Comment: Hi @VolkerK thanks for your input. It does contain input as:

=> 'C:\\Users\\Computer\\input.txt.txt', 23 => ! So this helped me to the solution, as the extension was not correctly parshed! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, you have  the `hide known file type extensions` "feature" on.

Comment: so that ^ is kind of related to what I said, yes? kind of lol

Comment: Sometimes features and bugs are indistinguishable ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the extension. It was not correctly parsed. This was checked by using @VolkerK suggesting to check

> Does the output of var_export(glob('C:\Users\Computer*')); contain
>   input.txt? Or is it false/null?

Thanks to @VolkerK for the help solving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Since I incorrectly said that it might be because of backslash escaping, I guess I need to redeem by saying something useful :)

So try:

```
$file = 'C:\Users\Computer\input.txt';
if(is_file($file))
{
  $string = file_get_contents($file);
} 
else
{
  die("Uh oh! Seems like $file has got problems!"); 
}
```

Also, you are passing the second argument as `true` for searching the include path. Since your filepath is absolute, I suspect if you need this argument to be passed at all.

Comment: There is no escaping in single-quoted strings (except escaping single quotes). And the error message shows that the backslashes were read properly.

Comment: I believe this is only when inside double quotes. Single quotes doesn't escape. Also, if you look at the error message, it specifically says `C:\Users\Computer\input.txt`